# Can I cancel a reviewed but not yet published Android app release of the Play Store?

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-console

I have managed publishing turned on for my Android App.

I have done a production release, and it has been reviewed, and is ready to be published.

Now I want to completely cancel this release, because the apk is broke. How can I do this?

Comment: Just push fixed upgrade

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you fix the app and have a new version, upload the new aab to production.

the production will cancel the old version.

Also in Managed publishing you can delete the reviewed version.

Answer (score 0):

If your apps was not released to production, you dont have to worry about it, but if you did a rollout of your app that is lower than 100%, you can go to

"All app" > Select your app > in the right menu go to "Production" > go to "Releases" > "Manage rollout", here you can stop the release with "Halt rollout"

[image]

otherwise, **if your app was completely released (100% of users)**:

[image]

**the only option is creating a new .APK or .AAB to upgrade your app and solve the issues.**